# how to fix org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android

can you please help me to fix the below error ?

07-07 18:36:54.049: E/pass 1(22845): connection success 
07-07 18:36:54.194: E/pass 2(22845): connection success 
07-07 18:36:54.194: E/Fail 3(22845): org.json.JSONException: Value

here is my below code

```
    public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));

        try
        {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost =new HttpPost("http://justedhak.comlu.com/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }     

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

        try
        {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", name: "+json_data.getString("name"))
                ;
        Log.e("pass 3", "connection success ");
    }}
        catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }  

}}
```

}

### EDIT

here is my `PHP`

```
<?php
    $host='mysql12.000webhost.com';
    $uname='a6901827_moudiz';
    $pwd='***';
    $db="a6901827_justed";


    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    $r=mysql_query("insert into samle values('$id','$name') ",$con)

    echo json_encode(1);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

this is the error

```
07-07 20:13:52.300: E/2(8837): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
07-07 20:13:52.300: E/2(8837): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in <b>/home/a6901827/public_html/insert.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
07-07 20:13:52.300: E/2(8837): <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>
07-07 20:13:52.300: E/Fail 3(8837): org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: ... `Value <br><table of type java.lang.String` .... obviously you didn't get json ...

Comment: How should i get it ? @selvin

Comment: Error is telling you that data which you received is not a json data. Response should contains informations about error. "<br><table" its probably part of error message. Please add full response to your post.

Comment: @404notfound how to add the response

Comment: You have variable `result` probably its a `String`. Print exactly what it contains in logcat and edit your post by adding it.

Comment: @404notfound check now please

Answer (score 0):

So It is your response

```
    <br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Access denied for user 'a6901827'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in <b>/home/a6901827/public_html/insert.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table><br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_select_db() [<a href='function.mysql-select-db'>function.mysql-select-db</a>]: Access denied for user 'a6901827'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in <b>/home/a6901827/public_html/insert.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table><br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'><b>PHP Error Message</b></font></td></tr></table><br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_select_db() [<a href='function.mysql-select-db'>function.mysql-select-db</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/a6901827/public_html/insert.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' bgcolor='#FFFFDF' bordercolor='#E8B900' align='center'><tr><td><div align='center'><a href='http://www.000webhost.com/'><font face='Arial' size='1' color='#000000'>Free Web Hosting</font></a></div></td></tr></table>Could not connect: Access denied for user 'a6901827'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If it does not tell you anything you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/91dk9p95/

Answer is easy, its  Access denied error returned by your database. Check credentials and try again.

Comment: Yes , I noticed that problem with user and pass I am fixing it

Comment: Tell me about a result.

Comment: I really appreciat your help, ofcourse Ill tell you about it one moment please

Comment: check now please my question

Comment: yes the credentials are correct , I recieved the echo from PHP but I want to convert string to json ..how to do that

Comment: You have to create object which you want to send in php and use this function on it https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php Die or echo result of json_encode

Comment: Yes, if $msg is variable which contains data you want return to user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82632/discussion-between-moudiz-and-404notfound).